# Could we use Magma to calculate subgroups of a fixed order?

Tags: group-theory, magma-cas

I know very little about the software Magma and I know it can be used in group theory. Here I have a problem, could someone tell me whether and how to calculate it using Magma?

Here is the problem: given a fixed group $G$, I want to know the number of its subgroups of fixed order. For example, Let $G$ be a Coxeter group of $B_3$, it has generators $s_1,s_2,s_3$ with relations $s_1^2=s_2^2=s_3^2=(s_1s_2)^4=(s_1s_3)^2=(s_2s_3)^3=1$. The order of $G$ is 48. I want to know whether could we use Magma to calculate the number of subgroups of order 8, 16?

Comment: This is just to point out that both the $\mathtt{LowIndexSubgroups}$ command used by Alex Best, and the $\mathtt{Subgroups}$ command used by verret do not return all subgroups. They return representatives of the conjugacy classes of subgroups in $G$.

Comment: There are actually a total of 7 subgroups of order 16, all conjugate in $G$, and $19$ of order $8$, forming one conjuagcy class of length $1$, and $6$ classes of length $3$.

Comment: @Derek Holt Thank you for pointing out that. So length means the number of subgroups conjugate to the subgroup got, is it right?

Comment: Yes, the $\mathtt{Subgroups}$ command returns a record. It has components $\mathtt{order}$, $\mathtt{length}$, and $\mathtt{subgroup}$, where the last of these is the subgroup itself.

Comment: @Derek Holt Ok, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this, following the documentation in the magma handbook we can do https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/841

```
>  G<s1,s2,s3> := Group< s1, s2, s3 | s1^2, s2^2, s3^2, (s1*s2)^4, (s1 * s3)^2, (s2*s3)^3>;
> Order(G);
48
> LowIndexSubgroups(G, <48 div 8, 48 div 8>);
[
Finitely presented group on 2 generators
Index in group G is 6 = 2 * 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s2 * s1
$.2 = s3 * s2 * s1 * s2 * s3 * s1,

Finitely presented group on 3 generators
Index in group G is 6 = 2 * 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s2
$.2 = s1 * s2 * s1
$.3 = s3 * s2 * s1 * s2 * s3 * s1,

Finitely presented group on 2 generators
Index in group G is 6 = 2 * 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s1
$.2 = s3 * s2 * s1 * s2,

Finitely presented group on 3 generators
Index in group G is 6 = 2 * 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s1
$.2 = s2 * s1 * s2
$.3 = s3 * s2 * s1 * s2 * s3 * s2,

Finitely presented group on 3 generators
Index in group G is 6 = 2 * 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s1
$.2 = s2 * s1 * s2
$.3 = s3 * s2 * s1 * s2 * s3,

Finitely presented group on 3 generators
Index in group G is 6 = 2 * 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s1
$.2 = s3
$.3 = s2 * s1 * s2 * s3 * s2 * s1 * s2,

Finitely presented group on 2 generators
Index in group G is 6 = 2 * 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s1
$.2 = s2
]
true
> 
> LowIndexSubgroups(G, <48 div 16, 48 div 16>);
[
Finitely presented group on 3 generators
Index in group G is 3
Generators as words in group G
$.1 = s1
$.2 = s2
$.3 = s3 * s2 * s1 * s2 * s3
]
true
```

This lists distinct conjugacy classes of subgroups and gives us generators in terms of the original ones $s_1,s_2,s_3$. If we just want the number of classes put a # in front:

```
> #LowIndexSubgroups(G, <48 div 16, 48 div 16>);
1
> #LowIndexSubgroups(G, <48 div 8, 48 div 8>);  
7
```

To get the actual number of subgroups, see Derek Holt's comment above.

Comment: Yes, but these are the numbers of conjugacy classes of subgroups, not the total numbers of subgroups.

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks for this important correction!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative to Alex's answer:

```
G<s1,s2,s3> := Group< s1, s2, s3 | s1^2, s2^2, s3^2, (s1*s2)^4, (s1 * s3)^2, (s2*s3)^3>;

f,GG:=CosetAction(G,sub<G|>);

Subgroups(GG:OrderEqual:=16);

Subgroups(GG:OrderEqual:=8);
```

The first line is the same, to define the group. The second turns the group into a permutation group GG (acting regularly on itself) with f the isomorphism from G to GG. Then it's self-explanatory. The advantage is that there are many more algorithms available for permutation groups than for finitely presented groups, and they are often faster. (Note that there are other, sometimes better way to turn a group into a permutation group, but this way always works, if magma can figure out the group is finite.)

You can use f to go from G to GG and back. For example, if you add at the end:

```
(Subgroups(GG:OrderEqual:=16)[1]`subgroup)@@f;
```

It will output:

Finitely presented group on 5 generators

Generators as words in group G

```
$.1 = s1
$.2 = s2
$.3 = Id(G)
$.4 = (s1 * s2)^2
$.5 = s1 * s3 * s2 * s1 * s2 * s3
```

Comment: Thank you. I have found many codes are not valid for FP groups. Your way is really very good and efficient.

Comment: Hello, sir. When I use your method in second step: f,GG :=CosetAction(G,sub);  Magma returns that Identifier 'sub' has not been declared or assigned.  Why does this happen?

Comment: It should be "sub<G|>" instead of "sub". It's ok in the source of my answer, but not displaying properly, probably because "<" is a special symbol. If anybody knows how to fix this, please do.

Comment: "sbu<G|>" is ok. Thank you again.

Comment: @verret: See "code and preformatted text" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).