# Finding random point of specified order using MAGMA

Tags: elliptic-curves, magma-cas

I would like to use MAGMA to construct a random point of specified order on an elliptic curve over a finite field. I have created the elliptic curve `E0`, but I'm not sure how to get the subgroup of points of a fixed order. There is a solution to this problem for general groups [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3463728/could-we-use-magma-to-calculate-subgroups-of-a-fixed-order) in the answer by verret, but trying to follow that produces an error:

```
> p := 2^216 * 3^137 - 1;
> Fp2 := GF(p^2);
> E0 := EllipticCurveWithjInvariant(Fp2 ! 1728);
> AbE0 := TorsionSubgroup(E0);
> PremE0 := CosetAction(AbE0, sub<AbE0|>);
>> PremE0 := CosetAction(AbE0, sub<AbE0|>);
                        ^
Runtime error in 'CosetAction': Coset table not finite
```

I tried this code with a small "toy" example of an abelian group and it worked fine, so I'm wondering if the issue is that the size of `AbE0` is just too large? `AbE0` is finite, but (very) large.

Finally, is there a better way of doing this for elliptic curves? Even if I am able to turn the group of points on `E0` into a permutation group and use the suggestions in the link to get the subgroup of order I'm interested in, then pick a random element, I will eventually want to use that element as a point on the curve, so I would need to translate back again. It seems there should be a better path...

Comment: How about `[P : P in AbE0 | Order(P) eq 12]`? (Or whatever order you want the point to have.) Or if you want the subgroup generated, `sub< AbE0 | S >` where `S` is the above sequence.

Comment: This is super helpful! I think in my case the group is just too large: I'm looking for the A-torsion subgroup where A = 2^216, so there should be 2^532 points. What I really need though is generators for the A-torsion subgroup. Is there a way I can get those without constructing the entire set of points of order A?

Comment: Also, thank you so, so much for your help! I'm just starting to learn magma for research and there's no expert on it in my department, so this is really invaluable to me :)

Comment: Can you include the actual definition of `E0` in your post? It's hard to give suggestions when I can't actually try them with your curve.

Comment: Added the code for constructing `E0`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in command to do this automatically in *Magma*, but it can be done using a few facts about elliptic curves and cyclic groups. Let $k = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. First, $E(k)$ is the direct sum of at most $2$ cyclic groups. (See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118649/why-is-the-abelian-group-of-points-on-an-elliptic-curve-over-a-finite-field-isom), for example.) For your curve, running

```
> [Factorization(Order(el)) : el in Generators(AbE0)];
[
[ <2, 216>, <3, 137> ],
[ <2, 216>, <3, 137> ]
]
```

we see that $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} E(k) \cong \frac{\Z}{2^{216} 3^{137} \Z} \oplus \frac{\Z}{2^{216} 3^{137} \Z}$. Calling these generators $P_1$ and $P_2$, then $Q_1 := 3^{137} P_1$ and $Q_2 := 3^{137} P_2$ generate the subgroups of order $2^{216}$ in their respective factors. Thus, any point of order $2^{216}$ in $E(k)$ can be written as $m_1 Q_1 + m_2 Q_2$ where $\gcd(2, m_1, m_2) = 1$. So to generate a random point of order $2^{216}$, it suffices to pick random $m_1$ and $m_2$ with these properties.

Comment: This works, thanks again!